# How to install Tridion Cache Channel windows Service using different host and port

Tags: 2013, cache-channel-service

We are using Tridion 2013 and want to install the Cache Channel Service using a different host and port than the default. The command `cd_cacheservice.exe -install -host=localhost:3030` is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SYSTEM->CurrentControlSet->Services->TCDCacheService
```

Change the value of the **ImagePath** for the parameters to pass to the Cache Channel Service. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\cd_cacheservice.exe" localhost:1066
```

This is documented on the following page:

[Installing the Cache Channel Service server role as a Windows service](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C042687E-EE48-405D-B8EE-83C823631E4B)

Comment: i m trying to change imagepath as u suggest but when i start service i m getting this error "Error 1053:the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

Comment: That seems like an unrelated error... Try going to the Tridion folder and running `java -cp "./config;./lib/*" com.tridion.cache.CacheChannelService` (documented here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-222C0D91-1137-4C45-8EDF-632572BB8C37 - login required)