# Can Multiple Deployers use the same Cache Channel Service installed as service on Windows machine

Tags: 2013-sp1, cache-channel-service

Tridion 2013 SP1 in use:
On Content Delivery Unix box we have multiple deployers running and Even Odata Web-service. And the Tridion Cache Channel Service is installed as windows service on single windows server Machine.

Now my query is can all the deployers and odata webservice can point to same CCS service installed on one machine or we must need multiple CCS service intances; where each CCS instance will serve only one deployer or web-service.

Answer (score 2):

The cache channel service should be shared by the deployer (which sends invalidation messages) and the web applications (which need to be informed of invalidations). So the deployer and the web applications have a shared interest in the content items that are being published.

The cleanest design for a scale-out is to ensure that there's no overlap of interests. So if you have two entirely independent web sites, each one is in its own publication, has its own publication target, deployer, CCS and web application. But this example is simple enough that you *could* actually share a deployer and CCS, as the publication ID would effectively partition the items.

In a more real-world scenario, you have a staging and a live site. Each deals with the same content, but the "published" state can be different in each. So a given item might be published at one version in the live site and at a different version in staging. Obviously, you don't want to have it so that publishing in staging invalidates the item in live, or vice versa, so these applications need a separate deployer and a separate CCS.

There's no reason why the CCS needs to be on the same server. If you need to run two on the same server, you need to control the port number. To do this in 2013, see [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/4804/129) and for an approach to doing the same thing in Web 8, see [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/16469/129).

Comment: Cronic - Hi Dominic for that staging and live site scenario if we have separate deployer for staging and live on separate boxes; and each deployer pointing to different Broker DB, then if we are using single CSS installation to serve both staging and live deployer, it will  invalidate the item on both (staging and dev) when the item is published  to any one of these (staging or live). Is this True? Does it not consider tcm_id + Broker as identifier to invalidate the item. ?

Comment: The CCS isn't aware of separate broker databases. You'll need a separate CCS.